# Ruby on Rails - Delete something from an array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, ruby, view

I have a question with this code. In this view I iterate over an array but I want to have the option to delete an entry from the array. Here is my code

## view

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Ware</th>
    <th>Anzahl</th>
    <th>Einzelpreis</th>
    <th>Gesamtpreis</th>
  </tr>
  <% counter = 0 %>
    <% $itemarray.each do |iarray| %>
    <tr>
      <% @items.each do |item| %>
        <% if iarray.to_i == item.id %>
          <th> <%= item.name %> </th>
          <th> <%= $anzahlarray[counter] %> </th>
          <th> <%= item.price.round(2) %> € </th>
            <% preistemp = preistemp = item.price * $anzahlarray[counter].to_f %>
          <th> <%= preistemp.round(2) %> € </th>

          <th> <%= link_to 'Show', item_path(item) %> </th>
          <th> <%= link_to 'Destroy', :hidden_param => 'counter' , method: :deleteshoppingcartentry(counter), data: {confirm: 'Are you sure?' }%></th>
        <% end %>
      <% end %>
    </tr>  
    <% counter += 1 %>
  <% end %>
</table>
```

## controller

```
def deleteshoppingcartentry
   $itemarray.delete_at($entrynumber)
   $anzahlarray.delete_at($entrynumber)

   redirect_to "/orders/new"
end
```

maybe you could help me out

Comment: what are you trying to delete?

Comment: Are you using any database? or you just keep your data in global variables?

Comment: no i in this case i dont use a database. i store it in a global Array variable and want to delete a certan entry from the array. the delete Option is listed with the items but i dont know how i can delete it.

Comment: Your code is very hard to understand: Where does $itemarray come from and where does @item come from? BTW: In ruby it's note neccesary to use a $ to declare a variable.

Then: In your 'destroy'-link you are calling the deleteshoppingcartentry with an attribute counter, but in your definition of this method you assign no attribute.

Comment: The global variables are filled from the cookies, and I use them in the whole  controller, so I declared them global. the attribute was just a test from me, but I am really clueless how i could delete the certain entry from the array.

Answer (score 1):

You can't delete items from a global array variable. Use a database instead. Learn more about Rails' [ActiveRecord](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_basics.html).